# free/changing variables in integrate

Tags: r, windows, variables, integrate

I am triing to integrate the following function accrding to h:

FUNCTION:

```
integralpos <- function(h){
  (h)^(m-1)*exp(-x[4]*h-(r[v]-h-x[5]*x[3] + 0.5*(x[6]^2)*x[3])^2/
                   (2*x[6]^2*x[3]))}
```

CALL:

```
integrate(integralneg, -Inf, 0, abs.tol = 1e-08)$val
```

This works fine if i have example values for all variables (exept h).

The problem arises when i try to nest the integrate function in a loop where the variables change. I use bobyqa for max. likelihood estimation according to the x. The function bobyqa change the values of x[.] but since integralpos is not defined as a function of x it does not "enter" there.

Can somebody help me out here? Is there a way to run integrate with changing variables? Is there another function?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you include the code with the loop?

Comment: @ Valegard234: Correct the title. It should be 'integrate' and not 'inegrate'. Otherwise it will not be included for searches for 'integrate'

Comment: Please note the error. The Call should be: 

`integrate(integralneg, -Inf, 0, abs.tol = 1e-08)$val` 

the next function is:

 `infinitesumn <- function(n,x){
  (exp(-x[2])*x[2]^n)/
  (factorial(n))*
  ((x[7]^n)/((factorial(n-1)*sqrt(2*pi*x[3]))*x[6]))*
  (integrate(integralneg, -Inf, 0, abs.tol = 1e-08)$val)}`

but its nestet in several other functions until it reaches the top level with the function `bobyqa() (library('nloptr'))`

Comment: one level up:\\`source('sumn.R')
firstinfinitesum <- function(n,x){ 
  i = 1
  repeat{
    
    savenew = infinitesumn(i,x) + saveold[q] +0*n
      q = q + 1
      saveold[q] = savenew

   i = i + 1
    # exit 

    if (2*abs(infinitesumn(i-1,x)) <= FTOL*(abs(savenew - infinitesumn(i-1,x)) + abs(savenew))) {break} #before: x$SCORE 
  
  }
savenew
}`

Comment: another level up: 

`Fri <- function(x){
log(exp(-1*(x[1]+x[2]))*frzero(x) +
  exp(-x[1])*firstinfinitesum(n,x) +
  exp(-x[2])*secondinfinitesum(m,x) + #lÃ¤uft bis hier
  secounddoublesum(m,x))
}
`
TOP LEVEL: 

`bobyqa(c(0.05, 0.05, 1,0.05, 0.5, 0.000001,0, 0), Fri, lower = c(0, 0, 0.99,0, 0, 0.0000001,0, 0), upper = c(0.99, 0.99, 1,0.99, 0.99, 0.99,0.99, 0.99))`

Please note that there are several other functions but I now included all relevant functions for the posted integarl

Comment: WHy `integralpos` in first line? Assuming it's a typo, write a wrapper function  `foointegrate<-function(h,x) integrate(integralpos(h,x).(etc)))`  .  You should be passing `h,m` **and** `x` to your `integralpos` function anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem by passing the variables as follows:

```
integrate(integralneg, -Inf, 0, abs.tol = 1e-08,x=x,r=r,m=m)$val
```

thx for the help